# android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter) crashes the program if the database connection is closed

Tags: android, listview

```
MyDatabaseHelper helper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = {
        "_ID",
        "Title",
        "Subtitle"
};
Cursor cursor = database.query("MyTable", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

// Notice the position of these 2 lines. Will NOT crash if I move them to the bottom.
database.close();
helper.close();

String[] fromColumns = {
    "Title",
    "Subtitle"
};
int[] toViews = {
    R.id.list_view_item_text_view_title,
    R.id.list_view_item_text_view_subtitle
};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_release_list_view);

// Crashed!
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

/**
 * Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
 * at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
 * at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getCount(CursorAdapter.java:202)
 * at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
 */
```

It only works when I close both the database and the database helper after `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`. I closed the database because I already got the result set in the `Cursor`. The `Cursor` is needed in the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, which is in turn needed by the `ListView`. Still it crashes. What does the ListView have to do with the database anyway?

Comment: Because `Cursor` has resultset reference only upto you closing cursor or db connection. After closing db connection it releases reference of database

Comment: So much for my theory then. I do notice that you initialize variable `adapter` but assign `mAdapter` to the ListView.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. The above snippet was a modification from my code, for easier reading. Correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is expecting a life query; it cannot use a closed query.

The ListView reads just enough rows from the adapter to fill the screen. Only after the user scrolls down will the ListView ask the adapter for more rows. So this means that the query still has to be alive when that happens.

In essence it means that you do not close the database before you close the activity that shows the ListView.

Comment: Not true. I have nearly 40 items on the ListView, displayed on a tiny 320x240 screen (6 items are on the screen at a time). I closed the database and database helper immediately after `listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`, and I can freely scroll the ListView without any problem.